# Crash when set TextView text

Tags: android

crash reporting catch two crashed after calling TextView.setText() with valid string (formated as "Session 16/09/2015 10:12")

on nexus7 with 5.0.2 and Galaxy S6 (SM-G925F) with 5.1.1
I cannot find steps to reproduce it

> Android: 5.0.2 Manufacturer: asus Model: Nexus 7
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.text.method.WordIterator.setCharSequence(java.lang.CharSequence,
>   int, int)' on a null object reference     at
>   android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:559)
>     at
>   android.widget.SpellChecker$SpellParser.parse(SpellChecker.java:516)
>     at android.widget.SpellChecker.spellCheck(SpellChecker.java:257)    at
>   android.widget.Editor.updateSpellCheckSpans(Editor.java:541)  at
>   android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:1017)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7667)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4050)   at
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3905)   at
>   android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:85)     at
>   android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3880) ....my code that
>   calls setText()

Does anybody seen something like this?  Seems android crashes when try use spellchecker and show suggestions. I`m going to disable it with

> android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"

May this help?

Comment: textview is not assign

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar what means "tv is not assing" ?

Comment: post your code please

Comment: There are no any special code. just a valid TextView and I call
tv.setText("Session 16/09/2015 10:12");
It does not happens always. There was just several crashes catched by HockeyApp and all on adroid 5

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider not a duplicate. Just take a look on stacktrace. It happens in Android code if i set valid string into EditText

Answer (score 0):

> public boolean isSuggestionsEnabled ()

Added in API level 14
Return whether or not suggestions are enabled on this TextView. The suggestions are generated by the IME or by the spell checker as the user types. This is done by adding SuggestionSpans to the text. When suggestions are enabled (default), this list of suggestions will be displayed when the user asks for them on these parts of the text. This value depends on the inputType of this TextView. The class of the input type must be TYPE_CLASS_TEXT. In addition, the type variation must be one of TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL, TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT, TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_LONG_MESSAGE, TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_SHORT_MESSAGE or TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_WEB_EDIT_TEXT. And finally, the **TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS flag must not be set.**

Returns
true if the suggestions popup window is enabled, based on the inputType.